# How to load Image from user's computer

Tags: c#, image, c#-4.0, xna, textures

Is it possible to load image to XNA game from user computer? For example, I want to load "C:\Images\Box.png" to sprite texture. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In XNA 4.0 use [`Texture2D.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434105.aspx)

```
Texture2D fileTexture;
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Images\Box.png", FileMode.Open))
{
    fileTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, fileStream);
}
```

---

If you're using XNA before 4.0 then you can use [`Texture2D.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.fromfile%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. And can I load it from .png file by this method?

Comment: According to the documentation `.gif, .jpg or .png` are supported, so yes.

Comment: Thank you so much as is possible!

Comment: If you're loading your own textures like this without the aid of the `ContentManager` you should also remember that you're responsible for disposing the texture yourself.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Images\Box.png", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
Texture2D texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, stream);
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the stream once you're finished. (with `stream.Dispose`, or a `using` statement like i've used).

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I see you even beat me to the solution :) +1 from me